# Are there any cross platform free tools for screen sharing that just work?

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, screen-sharing

I can't find a program for screen sharing, really. I mean it:

- **Cross platform**. **Windows, Mac and Linux**, not just Win+Mac.
- **Free**. Not free for personal use only (TeamViewer), not free for 1 month, just *free* as in "freedom".
- **Works**. Not cripled as Skype (Windows -> Linux screen sharing)
- **Simple**. Grandma-level.

Are these demands too high?

---

Discord - no screen sharing yet (and may become shit like Skype if it stays closed and MS buys it then)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "screen sharing", do you mean remote access? With one PC able to control the other, like TeamViewer? And file transfer?

If so, you cannot beat [TightVNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-tight/). I have been using it for years and highly recommend it.

It is truly free and runs on Widnows, Mac & Linux.

It is also "granny simple", after you have set it up. Just configure her PC as a TightVNC server and yours as a client and you are done.

Comment: Actually it is enough for me just to show a screen

Comment: I may be wrong but you can't tell your ma: "yo, you're behind NAT, get white IP4 address or open some ports". If someone agrees to this quest I will spend 1h min to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zoom.us](https://zoom.us/). It's really simple, works well on Windows and Android for sure,I haven't tested on Linux. For more than 2 people, there's a 40 minute time limit on free plan. But it's awesome for one-on-one chatting/screensharing/drawing, etc. And its very lightweight. Worth checking out.